# Parse from single node in multiple nodes that have same name

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

```
  <physicalResource>
    <prName>PRS_EID</prName>
    <prDescription>PRS_EID</prDescription>
    <physicalResourceCharacteristic>
        <characteristic>
            <name>eidno</name>
            <value>SH001499000</value>
        </characteristic>
        <characteristic>
            <name>flatno</name>
            <value>14303</value>
        </characteristic>
    </physicalResourceCharacteristic>
  </physicalResource>

  <physicalResource>
    <prName>PRS_OLT</prName>
    <prDescription>PRS_OLT</prDescription>          
    <physicalResourceCharacteristic>
        <characteristic>
            <name>device</name>
            <value>WC-OMU-AO01</value>
        </characteristic>
        <characteristic>
            <name>frame</name>
            <value>1</value>
        </characteristic>
        <characteristic>
            <name>port</name>
            <value>5</value>                
        </characteristic>
    </physicalResourceCharacteristic>   
  </physicalResource>
```

Hello Dears.. I have an xml file. It contains different nodes with same node name. In the example under physicalResource node, I want to extract prName and all characteristic's name and value. But I cant parse them seperately.
I'm using

```
nodeListPrs = root.SelectNodes("/physicalResource/physicalResourceCharacteristic/characteristic", nsmgr);
```

It extracts all charactics value for both nodes. How can i extract these parameters from single physicalResource node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. I have resolved by using SelectSingleNode and SelectNodes cascade:

```
XmlNodeList nodeListPrs = root.SelectNodes("/ns2:serviceOrder/resourceFacingService/physicalResource", nsmgr);
            foreach (XmlNode book in nodeListPrs)
            {
                string prsName = book["prName"].InnerText;

                try
                {
                    nodeListPrsCh = book.SelectSingleNode("physicalResourceCharacteristic").SelectNodes("characteristic");

                    foreach (XmlNode characteristics in nodeListPrsCh)
                    {
                        dataGridView3.Rows.Add();
                        dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = prsName;

                        try { string name = characteristics["name"].InnerText; dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = name; }
                        catch { dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "-"; }

                        try { string value = characteristics["value"].InnerText; dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = value; }
                        catch { dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = "-"; }

                        i = i + 1;
                    }
                }

                catch
                {

                    dataGridView3.Rows.Add();
                    dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = prsName;
                    dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "-";
                    dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = "-";
                    i = i + 1;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use xmldocument and load that xml to xmldocument then you can use selectsinglenode. It would help!!

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xml);
xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(path for the node..);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication78
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("physicalResource").Select(x => new {
                prName = (string)x.Element("prName"),
                characteristics = x.Descendants("characteristic").Select(y => new {
                       name = (string)y.Element("name"),
                       value = (string)y.Element("value")
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i can extract prName's. My problem is extracting characteristic. I used selectnodes(physicalResource/physicalResourceCharacteristic/characteristic). But ouput contains all for both of the physicalResource. I want to get them seperate for physicalResource node 1 and physicalResource node 2

Answer (score 0):

To select all `prName` nodes with the corresponding `characteristic` nodes of the first `physicalResourceCharacteristic` node, you would use the follwing XPath expression in `SelectNodes`.

```
/res/physicalResource[1]/physicalResourceCharacteristic/characteristic | /res/physicalResource[1]/prName
```

The result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prName>PRS_EID</prName>
<characteristic>
    <name>eidno</name>
    <value>SH001499000</value>
</characteristic>
<characteristic>
    <name>flatno</name>
    <value>14303</value>
</characteristic>
```

I'm not sure if this is what you strive for. You could iterate over the count of `physicalResource` constructing `[xxx]` XPath-expressions to get a nodeset with a couple of these entries. Or you could omit the `[1]` to get a nodeset with all `physicalResource`s prefixed by `prName`s, but with mixed node-types.